# PIP (picture in picture) with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

is it possible to implement PIP mode in Android 4.1+ app with ExoPlayer? iOS's AVPlayer has builtin functionality which allows to detach video and show it on desktop, I can't find solutions to implement such function on Android 4.1+.

Answer (score 0):

From Android O, you can have that feature by declaring supportsPictureInPicture in your activity manifest

```
<activity android:name="VideoActivity"
android:resizeableActivity="true"
android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
android:configChanges=
    "screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
...
```

Comment: what if my app for API 16?

Comment: You need to create a service and use WindowManager to add a view

I posted a code snippet of how I did it for API 16.

https://pastebin.com/UCU39Em6